# I need a flash effect like this http://www.contempo.org.mo/Online%20magazine/ISSUE21/index.htm

Tags: html, flash, actionscript

Please refer to http://www.contempo.org.mo/Online%20magazine/ISSUE21/index.htm
Is there any open source or other tools can accomplish this ?
If I need to develop it by our own, what technology can we use? please give me more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an open source version:
http://pageflip.hu/

Here are two more pay-for versions:

http://page-flip.com/

http://www.flashpageflip.com/

The code behind the page-flipping technique is all very similar.  You ca read about how it is accomplished in the book [Flash Hacks](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596006457) - Chapter 3.

**EDIT**
It appears the pageflip.hu version is no longer open-sourced.  However, this one is:
http://www.megazine3.de/home.html